# How to only run function when button is submitted with key "Enter" - React Js

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, page-refresh, enter

Excuse the silly title :)

I have a button which when clicked runs a function called `restart` which simply resets a state. I want to make this button easily accessible, so when you press the tab, the button highlights prompting you to either press enter or click it.

**basic code**

```js
class Home extends Component{
  restart(){
    this.setState({popup:false,finished:true,started:false,userInput:""})
  }
  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        <button className="btn btn-dark buttons" onClick={this.restart.bind(this)}>Restart</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
```

Everything works fine if you click the button, but when pressing `Enter`, the page is reloaded which is quite harmful.

How might I be able to disable this reload when the button is submitted using the `Enter` key, and still call the `restart` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to use a `form` and call your `restart` method on the `onSubmit` event. This way it's accessible for keyboard users as well. Don't forget to call [`event.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) to not to reload the page.

Check out the demo below:

```js
class Home extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { popup: true, finished: false, started: true, userInput: '' };
    this.restart = this.restart.bind(this);
  }

  restart(e) {
    // make sure you don't reload the page
    e.preventDefault();

    this.setState({
      popup: false,
      finished: true,
      started: false,
      userInput: '',
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.restart}>
        <button className="btn btn-dark buttons" type="submit">
          Restart
        </button>
        <pre>
          {JSON.stringify(this.state, null, 2)}
        </pre>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Home />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: what is the <pre> tag doing here?

Comment: It's just for this demo to display the `state` as a preformatted text.

Comment: oh ok. Thank you. I'll try this out.

Comment: Hey @BuddyBob, did my solution worked? Could you click the checkmark (✓) to accept it if it answered your question? Thanks

Comment: Sadly, it didn't. Forgot to get back to you about it. I went with a totally different approach as this post was not getting any answers. Though I might just leave this post up here in case you answer might solve other user's question. Thank you!